# Escaping special characters in web2py database connection strings

Tags: python, web2py

I am using web2py to connect to a db with an 'at' sign in the password, eg 'P@sswd' .

```
db = DAL('mysql://user1:P@sswd@localhost/test')
```

This gets interpreted as a connection to host 'sswd@localhost' using password 'P'.

I have tried the obvious URL escaping technique but this failed:

```
db = DAL('mysql://user1:P%40sswd@localhost/test')
```

Is there a resource that explains the escaping conventions used in these URL style connection strings?

Comment: Your second example works just fine with SQLAlchemy's `create_engine()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `decode_credentials` option:

```
db = DAL('mysql://user1:P%40sswd@localhost/test', decode_credentials=True)
```

Comment: Hmm, why would this be needed btw? Shouldn't `'mysql://user1:P@sswd@localhost/test'` work out of the box?